# How to change background color of MessageBox in wpf using Telerik Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

I need to set background color for messagebox to show variation in alert message. I tried to implement using Telerik messagebox control as below:

**Name space:**

```
xmlns:messageBox="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.MessageBox;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Primitives"
```

**Style:**

```
<Style TargetType="messageBox:RadMessageBoxControl">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

**In code behind,**

```
Telerik.WinControls.RadMessageBox.Show("Do you want to close?", "Confirmation", Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, Telerik.WinControls.RadMessageIcon.Question)
```

There is a conflict between **Telerik.WinControls.dll** and **Telerik.Windows.Controls.Primitives.dll** while implementing the above code. 
Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

I have already checked for MessageBox customization and it exist for Windows form customization. I want solution to change default style of RadMessageBox of Telerik control.

Comment: check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734796/how-to-customize-message-box

Comment: Thank you @NAVEENKUMAR which is solution to windows form I want to write style in WPF

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize message box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734796/how-to-customize-message-box)

Comment: Wait, is it a WPF app? why use Telerik.WinControls.dll if its a winforms dll?